# React state not setting Object from temporary variable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I apologize, I know this is a common question but I just can't find the right answer. I'm using a functional component that gets a list of JSON objects from an API. The list data does not have all the information I need so I am iterating through a list of the provided IDs and fetching each 'show' JSON that DOES have the info I need. I then put those into an Array in state. It's messy, bit it works well enough. While I am iterating and fetching the individual 'show' JSON I have some math I want to do with some of the values. I'm putting that info into an object, but when I try to set that object to state it just doesn't work, even though I can log the object and it presents as expected.

```
  const getStashList = async () => {
        <Code to fetch list data>
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getStashList()
    }, [])

const getFullStashData = (data) => {
        const tempWeightObj = {}
        let fullStashArray = []
        try {
            data.forEach(async (stashItem) => {
                const indStashResponse = await fetch(`<the api address>`, {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token
                    },
                    mode: 'cors'
                })
                const indStashData = await indStashResponse.json()
                fullStashArray.push(indStashData.stash)

                const amountStashed = indStashData.total_yards

                let weightName = indStashData.weight_name
                Object.defineProperty(tempWeightObj, weightName, {
                    value: amountStashed,
                    writable: true
                })
                console.log(tempWeightObj) //This logs the expected object
            })
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(`Error in fetch: ${err.message}`)
        }
        setFullStash(fullStashArray) //This state is set as expected
        setWeightYards(tempWeightObj) //The state is still empty

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getFullStashData(stashList)
    }, [stashList])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of the `getFullStashData` function is completely synchronous. It declares `tempWeightObj` and `fullStashArray`, runs the `forEach` synchronously, and enqueues the state updates. The `async` `forEach` loop callbacks then mutate the references closed over in function scope.

What you are seeing is the mutation.

I suggest a refactor that declares the `getFullStashData` function to be `async`, map the `data` argument to an array of `fetch` Promise objects, await the array of responses to map to another array of Promise objects this time returning the JSON data. You've now the `fullStashArray` array to update state. Iterator over this `fullStashArray` array to populate the properties of the `tempWeightObj` object. Once all is complete *then* enqueue the state updates.

```
const getFullStashData = async (data) => {
  try {
    const reqs = data.map((stashItem) =>
      fetch(`<the api address>`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token
        },
        mode: "cors"
      })
    );
    const responses = await Promise.all(reqs);
    const fullStashArray = await Promise.all(responses.map((res) => res.json()));

    const tempWeightObj = {};
    fullStashArray.forEach(
      ({ total_yards: value, weight_name: weightName }) => {
        Object.defineProperty(
          tempWeightObj,
          weightName,
          { value, writable: true }
        );
      }
    );

    setFullStash(fullStashArray);
    setWeightYards(tempWeightObj);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error in fetch: ${err.message}`);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! I figured my issue had something to do with synchronicity but wasn't sure how to remedy.

Comment: @MFarron Were you able to resolve your question/issue with this answer?

Comment: I refactored and the code is cleaner and better but I still am not getting state to set. I pretty much used the same code as you but had to return something for the map and change how the object parameters were accessed for the forEach. The tempWeightObj is still logging as expected and weightYards state is still empty :/

Comment: @MFarron No worries. Do you think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo of this code that we could inspect and debug live? You can mock the `fetch` function and return a valid response values so the code runs through and processes it.

Comment: I have a silly question... how do you suggest I mock the fetch function? I made a mock API but now I have too many modules to make a sandbox

Comment: @MFarron Oh, I usually write a local function in the sandbox like `const fetch = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {resolve(/* response object with whatever your code is expecting to process, like a json function, etc... */)}, 3000));`. Make sense?

Comment: More or less. I got the mock data working but it's not working the way it does in my production environment. Object.defineProperty is not working and my state set for full stash is also not working. https://codesandbox.io/s/stupid-api-fetch-qnfjp1?file=/src/components/NewStashList.js

I will continue trying to get it to work later.

Comment: Stash state was setting after all. It looks like the code sandbox react dev tools were a little behind. Anyway I got it to work with my mock data by replacing Object.defineProperty (which was not working in the sandbox) with a spread operation. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: @MFarron Ok, I'll take a look when I've a moment. Yeah, I was actually wondering about the `Object.defineProperty` and why you didn't just create an object and shallow copy/spread in the values you wanted.

Comment: I was having issues with spread not working the way I expected. I thought defineProperty would work ok because I was mutating a temporary object and then setting it to state but I guess the synchronicity issues were still there. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @MFarron Oh, sorry, I never got back to checking your sandbox. Do you still need that looked at? Can you refresh me on any lingering issues and reproduction steps?

Comment: No worries! Nope it's all working now. :)

Comment: @MFarron Ok, then cheers and good luck!